# Apache returns 400 instead of 200 at DocumentRoot

Tags: apache-2.2, logging, 400, http-status-code

I am seeing a lot of these odd entries in my Apache access log:

```
SOME IP ADDRESS - - [23/Feb/2012:03:06:38 -0800] "GET /" 400 460 "-" "-"
```

If I try to access the Apache document root, I get:

```
MY IP ADDRESS - - [24/Feb/2012:09:37:28 -0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5464 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13"
```

How was the other IP able to produce a 400 instead of 200?

Answer (score 2):

It didn't send an `HTTP` version string (`HTTP/1.1` or `HTTP/1.0`), that client is not speaking correct HTTP.

It should most certainly get a `400 Bad Request` response.  See [RFC 2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt):

> The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax.

Comment: Note that while it is technically not standards-compliant Apache (2.2.x) will apparently answer a naked `GET /` request.  In my brief testing the reply doesn't include any HTTP headers though (If you can't be bothered to send a well-formed HTTP request the server can't be bothered to send a properly-formatted response either).